# How can I remove invalid entries (or pointers) from a GIT reposiory that uses LFS?

Tags: git, pointers, git-lfs

We added some png to our git repository with git lfs. Somehow something went wrong and a couple of file have bad entries with slashes in the wrong way

```
data/images\\picture1.png
data/images\\picture2.png
```

The real files exists and work OK

```
data/images/picture1.png
data/images/picture2.png
```

Now if I pull, I get an error

```
$ git.exe pull --progress --no-rebase -v "origin"
From bitbucket.org:USER/REP
= [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
Pointer file error: Unable to parse pointer at: "data/images\\picture1.png"
```

I've tried alread git rm and gc but with no luck. Is there a way to delete those entries directly from git DB?

Issue is on Windows, Linux and Mac

EDIT

Running git ls-files, I can see the files in the list, something like

```
  data/images/picture0.png
  "data/images\\picture1.png"
  "data/images\\picture2.png"
  data/images/picture3.png
```

if I try git rm with all kind of flavours (quotes, no quote, --force, --cache, --dry-run), I always receved the error

```
fatal: pathspec '"data/images\\picture1.png"' did not match any files
```

Comment: And Git version you are using is?

Comment: Latest one. I'm using bitbucket repository

Comment: just in case for local git version => 2.10.1.windows.1

Comment: Run `git remote update` first. Then, show output of `git ls-files '*.png' origin/master`

Comment: The list contains the files between quotes (the other are not quoted)

Comment: Try this procedure: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up recreating the respository from scratch and the problem went away by itself. It was probably due to one of many issues that currently affect git LFS..